# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' despite full grants for user root

Tags: mysql

I've logged into the user root and tried running the following command:

```
mysql>     GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON cms.* TO 'support'@'localhost';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'cms'
```

Root has full privileges but can make all the changes. Here's the grants for the root user.

```
mysql> show grants for root@localhost;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*929CD22466796BD0C90085810B3CCCA372C6B5D7' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a grant on 127.0.0.1 even though 'support'@'127.0.0.1' doesn't exist:

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON cms.* TO 'support'@'127.0.0.1';
```

For some reason all these queries started working:

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON cms.* TO 'support'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON cms.* TO 'support'@'172.29.20.%';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```